# java joda-time get date time

Tags: java, jodatime

In, Java how to use Joda-Time to get date and time using time zone. The server is running UTC +0300. But I need to use UTC +0530 i.e. *Indian standard time*. I need to use like this

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Calcutta");
```

But how to get date and time in this format : `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
    = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Then you can `.print()` your `DateTime`:

```
// Returns a String
FORMATTER.print(new DateTime(zone));
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers were partial. Here's a bit more info.

To adjust for time zone, you can either:

- Create a new DateTime instance with a different time zone assigned.
- Have the formatter apply a time zone during the creation of the string representation of the date-time.

```java
DateTime dateTimeMoscow = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Moscow" ) );
DateTime dateTimeIndia = dateTimeMoscow.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss").withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
String output = formatter.print( dateTimeMoscow ); // Formatter adjusts zone from Moscow to Kolkata.
```