# How to find out GMT offset value in android

Tags: android, gmt

How to find out the values of GMT for user for example it is +05:30 for India.
How do calculate this +05:30  value in Android ?

I need this because I am using a java library in my app which has a function with this +05:30  field and I want to generate this field by calculation so that I wont have to fill up individual values for countries.

Comment: Use calendar.getTimeInMillis(); returns the UTC time and compare it with GMT using Epoch http://www.xav.com/time.cgi

Comment: I am looking for an offline solution,if its possible

Comment: There is no +5.5 for [time zone offsets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) that I know of. Offsets are hours + colon + minutes, using double-digits with a padding zero if needed. India time is `+05:30` from UTC. Ignoring the padding zero will break various date-time libraries and interoperability.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java joda-time get date time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952989/java-joda-time-get-date-time) and many others. Search for "Asia/Kolkata" or "joda DateTimeZone".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what works awesome

```
   public double getOffset(){
        TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        int seconds = timezone.getOffset(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)/1000;
        double minutes = seconds/60;
        double hours = minutes/60;
        return hours;
  }
```

Comment: The above method returns an offset value and works for all gmts

Comment: How to determine if offset is plus or minus?

Answer (score 0):

First get the epoch system time

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Then use a date object, set the time zone to GMT and initialize with the long valye

```
dateObj.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get time in `GMT` use  below function where `dateInString` is the value of date,and `format` is date format as `yyyyMMddHH`

```
   public static long getDate(String dateInString,String format){
       long date = 0;
       SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

       try {
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date d = dateFormat.parse(dateInString);
        date = d.getTime();
       } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return date;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to get UTC :-

```
public int GetUnixTime()
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long now = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    int utc = (int)(now / 1000);
    return (utc);

}
```

after you get UTC now compared it to the Epoch in this site http://www.xav.com/time.cgi.

see this below link :-

[How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you store a map between timezones and their GMT offsets in your app, you can call TimeZone.getDefault() to get the device's timezone and do a quick lookup to return the GMT offset.  That way you don't have to rely on potentially tricky date/time calculations and can be sure you have the correct value.