# How to get the timezone offset in android?

Tags: java, android, time, offset

I found some similar questions, such as:

[How to get the timezone offset in GMT(Like GMT+7:00) from android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068113/how-to-get-the-timezone-offset-in-gmtlike-gmt700-from-android-device)

[How to find out GMT offset value in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358774/how-to-find-out-gmt-offset-value-in-android)

But all these answers(`+12:00`) are incorrect for New Zealand Daylight Saving Time now.

When I did debug, I got this from Google Calendar event object:

`"dateTime" -> "2016-11-06T10:00:00.000+13:00"`

So how to get the correct offset which should be `+13:00`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

To get the current offset from UTC in milliseconds (which can vary according to DST):

```
return TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

To get a RFC 822 timezone String instead, you can simply create a SimpleDateFormat instance:

```
return new SimpleDateFormat("Z").format(new Date());
```

The format is (+/-)HHMM

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried to get gmt offset through *Calendar* and *SimpleDateFormat* but both returns 0. I found the solution using deprecated methods in Date class.
So, this code works for me.

```
private double getOffset() {                                       
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);      
    int defHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);              
    int defMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + (defHour * 60);
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());              
    int curHour = date.getHours();                                 
    int curMinute = date.getMinutes() + (curHour * 60);            
    double offset = ((double) curMinute - defMinute) / 60;         
    return offset > 12? -24 + offset : offset;                     
}
```

Then you can format a result

Answer (score 0):

This code return me GMT offset.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"), Locale.getDefault());
Date currentLocalTime = calendar.getTime();
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
```

It returns the time zone offset like this: +0530